# Does tfs teambuild continuous-integration always building latest sources?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We've got quite a long build time and sometimes get a small queue of CI builds waiting to build, it looks to me like CI always builds 'latest sources' and not necessarily 'repository head plus changeset at time of checkin' - is that correct? and if so there's no point in waiting for each build of my queue to complete, I might as well cancel all but the last one?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you would prefer using [Rolling builds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308011%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) if you want to accumulate until the previous build finishes.

Comment: Thanks, suppose I've got ten queued codesets, and the 3rd one's going to fail; I'd like to see codeset1 and 2 pass before watching 3..10 fail. I don't want to see build 1 (codeset1) pass and then build 2 (codesets 2..10) fail. Have I misunderstood what CI does?

Comment: Have a look at the different build types on the link I sent. Maybe Gated Builds would be helpful for you also. Most companies we consult with use this and the percentage of 'broken builds' goes down significantly